# Template system for juju config files

Tags: juju, templates

I'm writing a Juju Charm that has a config file template where some values have to be filled in depending on the configuration. Is there a better way to do this than just using sed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use simple string replacement in my Ghost charm. You could do something similar with Python if you didn't want to install any additional languages.

utils.js: https://github.com/hatched/ghost-charm/blob/master/utils/utils.js

config.js.template https://github.com/hatched/ghost-charm/blob/master/assets/config.js.template

Comment: Thanks! I also found out about saltstack, I might use that to write install hooks in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[Juju has support for saltstack.](https://micknelson.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/easier-juju-charms-with-python-helpers/)

[Saltstack](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/) is a config management tool that makes writing install hooks a lot easier. You can also use the saltstack template functionality to make config files.